# How do we transfer a Sitecore/ASP.NET session between domains on the same delivery cluster?

Tags: best-practices, session-state

A bit about our setup.  We have 3 Sitecore 8.2U5 Content Delivery Servers across one Analytics node. We have SSO through a 3rd party provider (PING), a main site, and some portal sites.

The portal sites have a different domain and is generally the domain one is logging into. When a user logs into this portal, they are on `http://domain1.maindomain.com`. Now, this particular portal has white labeling functionality that allows clients to white label their portal for their company.  An example of this domain is `http://clientname.domain.maindomain.com`.  A wildcard DNS entry is utilized so that domains can be automatically added.  There are numerous subdomains.

However, members of a white label domain could also be members of the main portal domain.  **And we want to move the user seamlessly between the two when they so choose to.**

We have configured Sitecore to utilize SQL Shared Session state for Analytics, and we have setup the CD's to utilize SQL for Private Session State.

However, when the user jumps between the two subdomains, we lose the session state.

**How do we transfer a Sitecore/ASP.NET session between domains on the same delivery cluster (even same CD server) without losing that session?**

Comment: Did you try with <httpCookies domain=".maindomain.com"/> in the web.config?

Comment: Even if you solve the subdomain issue, you’re going to get stuck on CNAME domains because cookies are designed to be isolated.  That said there’s various options available with a robust discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies ... is moving the sessionId to the query string an option?